# Objective-C 2D Interpolation

Tags: objective-c, matlab

Has anyone come across an Objective-C equivalent to the MATLAB function [interp2](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/interp2.html)()?
...a 2D interpolation.

Cheers,
Brett

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [Numerical Recipes in C](http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf.php), Chapter 3 (especially section 3.6) and you should be able to do it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is simply a programming language. Higher-level functions such as interpolation, especially 2D interpolation, would be part of some library that you would use *with* Objective-C. Since Objective-C is derived from C, any suitable C library should work fine. Unfortunately, I wouldn't know which libraries to recommend.